# Group Isomorphic to $(\Bbb Z \oplus \Bbb Z )/\langle(4,2)\rangle $

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I wanted to find group isomorphic to $(\Bbb Z \oplus \Bbb  Z )/\langle(4,2)\rangle $. 
I don't know how to calculate that .I think it may be isomorphic to $(\Bbb Z_4 \oplus \Bbb  Z )$ or $(\Bbb Z_2 \oplus \Bbb  Z )$ 
From Hint provided Below : 

$(\Bbb Z \oplus \Bbb  Z )$= $(\Bbb Z(2,1) \oplus \Bbb  Z(1,0) )$ and $\langle (4,2) \rangle  $=$2\langle (2,1)\rangle$
So
 $(\Bbb Z \oplus \Bbb  Z )/\langle(4,2)\rangle $=$(\Bbb Z(2,1) \oplus \Bbb  Z(1,0) )$/$2\langle (2,1)\rangle$= $(\Bbb Z_2 \oplus \Bbb  Z )$
Is this right?

Any Help will be appreciated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $$f:\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}_2,\ f(x,y)=(x-2y,y)$$

Here $$ f((x,y)+(a,b)) =(x+a-2y-2b,y+b) =f((x,y))+f((a,b))
$$ is a group homomorphism.

And the kernel is $(  4t,2t)$ so that $\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$ is desired.

Comment: Sir Very Elegant Solution .I now understand to use factor group to define homomorphism .But One doubt is that I can go in following manner I know kernel and domain so I can find homomorphism .But I am not able to convince my self about Range Why $Z \times Z_2$? Please Help me out

Comment: Note that by $x$, $(x-2,1),\ (x-0,0)$ represent any element in $\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir .That means for kernel (kb,k) homomorphism will be f(x,y)=(x-ky,y) and Isomorphic to $Z \times Z_k$  .Is this possible to only (kb,k) form or also true in case of any (a,b) where a and b may be any thing even relatively prime ?

Comment: $f: \mathbb{Z}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{Z},\ f(x,y)=ay-bx$

Comment: Great Sir .Thanks a Lot....

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* Take $v_1=(2,1)$ and $v_2=(1,0)$. Then $\mathbb Z^2 = \mathbb Z v_1  \oplus \mathbb Z v_2$ and your subgroup is $2\mathbb Z v_1$.

Comment: Sir ,Great Solution .But for me choice of $v_1 , v_2$ is very unnatural .In sense that if I have any other problem I can not choose this directly .Is this with practice I get or is there any algorithm for choice of this $v_1 , v_2$.Thanks A lot for Reply

Comment: @SRJ, ask a separate question for the general case $(\Bbb Z \oplus \Bbb Z )/\langle(a,b)\rangle$.

Comment: @SRJ, the general algorithm is the [Smith normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form).